# Set socket timeout for HttpClient via system properties

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I have java app based on apache HttpClient. I want to inrease socket timeout without app changes(no timeout setting available in app). How can i do it via system properties(or other way without change app)?

Comment: or other way -> or other way without change app

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can do it easily in code:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout",
    Integer.getInteger("http.socket.timeout", <defaultValue>);
```

(Note that `Integer.getInteger(String, int)` reads an integer value from the given system property)

Comment: Thank you! But i want to inrease socket timeout without change the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring to read system properties like below:

```
<bean id="yourBean" class="com.company.YourBean">
    <property name="httpClientTimeout" 
                value="#{ systemProperties['httpclient.timeout'] }"/>
    <!-- where httpclient.timeout is system variable-->
    <!-- other properties goes here....-->
</bean>
```

Once you have the timeout value, you can set the timeout to HttpClient.

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeout);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestURL);
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Read the timeout from properties file and pass it to this code snippet.

Comment: Thank you! But i want to inrease socket timeout without change the code.